# Delegated permissions can be used, even if I am not using the app

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0

When consenting as a user to delegated permissions an app requests in the Azure portal, I always find a note in the top, saying "Maintain access to data you have given it access to", like:

[image]

What I do not understand is the phrase:
"Allows the app to see and update the data you gave it access to, **even when you are not currently using the app**"

How do I understand this? I thought that after I consent to this, the app can get an access token for the requested data, but only ***for the lifetime*** of this access token.
When I never use the app again, the app wont have another valid access token, therefore cannot access my data, right?
But why should the app use my data, when I am not using it?

For application permissions I would understand the phrase... but in this case it does not make a lot sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the app also gets a *refresh token* that it can use to get new access tokens when needed.
They are a feature of OAuth.
Refresh tokens can be revoked for various reasons, as this documentation shows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#token-revocation.

If they did not exist, the app would have to redirect you to authenticate again every hour.

We have used refresh tokens to build background synchronization processes for example.

Comment: ahh.. of course. I forgot about refresh tokens :) Thanks.